# Convert decimal to binary using recursion

Tags: java

I got the following code:

```
public class decToBin {

public static void main(String args[]) {

    int number = 32;

    System.out.println(decToBinWrapper(number));
}

public static String decToBinWrapper(int number) {

    return decToBin(number, "");
}

public static String decToBin(int number, String bin) {
    if (number >= 1)
        return decToBin(number / 2, bin + Integer.toString(number % 2));
    else
        return "0";

}
}
```

which is supposed to convert a decimal to binary but it only prints "0" instead of the binary string. Could someone tell me what I'm doing wrong please?

Comment: Just in case it's useful to you: Integer.toBinaryString()

Comment: There is no decimal here. `number` is already binary.

Answer (score 3):

You should return the `bin` variable:

```
else
    return bin;
```

You also want to *prepend* `Integer.toString(number % 2)` to the previous String, not append it:

```
return decToBin(number / 2, Integer.toString(number % 2) + bin);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
else
    return "0";
```

I think you probably meant `return bin`, since you're accumulating into that string.  You're just discarding `bin` in your current implementation.

Comment: He also needs to *prepend* values, not append to make the digit order be correct